# Query LINQ - Could not find an implementation of the query pattern

Tags: c#, linq

I created a table in my designer view with 4 columns. I'd like to add others columns manually (because it'll be add according the data stored in DB).
I would like to create the link between the data from DB and the table so I did this :

```
private void LoadSiteDataSource()
{
    CVaultDataSource.Rows.Clear();

    if (this.Site != null)
    {
         var sitesDB = from sites in this.Site
                       select sites.KEY;

         foreach (var item in sitesDB)
         {
             CVaultDataSource.Rows.Add(item);
         }
    }
}
```

But I have this error :

> Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type System.ComponentModel.ISite. 'Select not found'.

I've look the differents topics about this error but I could not find something to fix it.

I'm already using this function which works :

```
private void LoadDataSource()
{
    CVaultDataSource.Rows.Clear();

    if (this.BaseFilters != null)
    {
        var filters = from filterBase in this.BaseFilters
                        orderby filterBase.EVPTCODE
                        select new object[] { filterBase.CVAULTCODE, filterBase.EVPTCODE, filterBase.EVPTDESIGNATION, filterBase.DURATION, filterBase.ETDTIME };

        foreach (var item in filters)
        {
            CVaultDataSource.Rows.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Does someone know why it does not work ?

Comment: Either delete this (now solved question), or put an answer below that describes in enough detail what you did wrong and what the solution was.  The second is preferable for a new user, as it's less likely to count against an autoban.  For more info, visit [meta].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just forget to declare this :

```
public List<SITE> Sites { get; private set; }
```

That's why it did not work.